# 500 Internal Server Error - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I get this error :

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@vitrinsaz1.ir to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

content of my `.htaccess` :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 php53 php

php_flag  log_errors on
php_flag  display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 8
php_value error_reporting E_ALL
php_value error_log  /domains/vitrinsaz1.ir/public_html/error_log2

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vitrinsaz1.ir$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/$1 [R=301,L]



RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>


order allow,deny
allow from all
```

I think my `.htaccess` is ok but when I remove the content of my `.htaccess` every thing become ok.

Comment: Look in the error logs to see the exact error message.

Comment: Check your name server settings aswell. Common cause of issue.

Comment: .htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: How are you running PHP? `php_*` values in `.htaccess` can only be read with mod_php as far as I know (as in you need to use a different approach with php-fpm for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `AllowOverride All` in your default virtualhost config file (default path : `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`) or for a specific virtualhost.

By default `AllowOverride` is set to `None`

Answer (score 0):

php_flag is not allowed in PHP CGI mode